# how do i convert this piece of code into javascript function?

Tags: javascript

i have a form where it has the default value prompting user to enter data.

here is my form.

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="input-text" value="Enter Name..." onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Name...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter Name...';}" />

<input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="input-text" value="Enter Email Address..." onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Email Address...') { this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.value ='Enter Email Address...';}"/>

<textarea name="message" id="message" class="input-textarea" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter your Message...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter your Message...';}">Enter your Message...</textarea>
```

there are lots of code repeatation here. i want to convert the below code into the javascript function.

```
onfocus="if(this.value == 'Enter Name...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter Name...';}"
```

how do i do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do i convert this piece of code into javascript function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139460/how-do-i-convert-this-piece-of-code-into-javascript-function)

Comment: @Alnitak: As this is the first question, it's the other that is a duplicate.

Comment: yes, i am sorry about it. didn't quite notice it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than including any code 'in-line' you could do:

```
function autoHideDefault(el) {
    var defaultValue = el.value;
    el.onblur = function() { 
        if(this.value == '') this.value = defaultValue ;
    }
    el.onfocus = function() {
        if(this.value == defaultValue) this.value = '';
    }
}

autoHideDefault(document.getElementById('name'));
autoHideDefault(document.getElementById('email'));
autoHideDefault(document.getElementById('message'));
```

Comment: the code gives me following error e1 is null . even when it holds the value. what could be possibly wrong?

Comment: You haven't passed the element correctly - make sure you're calling it after the form and that the ids are correct and unqiue.

Comment: i am not sure what is going wrong, now it is giving me whole lot of different problem ill post another question. thank you for your help. i really like the way you represented the code it is neat :)

Comment: -1 just because you are downvoting other solutions only because they are not your solution

Comment: Actually I upvoted one and downvoted another. That's actually what I think, rather than a bitter reaction to a valid comment.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you might be looking for HTML5's `placeholder` attribute. Usage as follows:

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"
    class="input-text" placeholder="Enter Name..." />

<input type="text" id="email" name="email"
    class="input-text" placeholder="Enter Email Address..." />

<textarea name="message" id="message"
    class="input-textarea" placeholder="Enter your Message..."></textarea>
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NUWNq/)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, you can use something like this to pick up the lead text from each element and change it on focus and blur:

```
$(function(){
  $('.input-text,.input-textarea').each(function(){
    var lead = $(this).val();
    $(this).focus(function(){
      if($(this).val() == lead) $(this).val('');
    }).blur(function(){
      if ($(this).val().length == 0) $(this).val(lead);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 i think this is the best one that we can do using JQuery which eliminate multiple lines of code.Cheers...

Comment: Why would you use jQuery when the code is exactly equivalent to the 'vanilla' version, except with all the added overhead of downloading jQuery, initiating objects (on each val() call, no less).

Comment: @Hamish: You would use jQuery for this if you were already using jQuery. If you read the answer again, and start from the beginning, you will see that I started the answer with that exact condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
function gainFocus(element, text) {
    if(element.value == text) {
        element.value = '';
    }
}

function loseFocus(element, text) {
    if(element.value == '') {
        element.value = text;
    }
}
```

Then, you can use the two function in your element :

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="input-text" value="Enter Name..." onfocus="gainFocus(this, 'Enter Name...');" onblur="loseFocus(this, 'Enter Name...')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly scary looking, but minimally increasing upon more fields, solution:

```
function fieldFocus(m, e) {
    if (e.target.value == m) e.target.value = '';
}
function fieldBlur(m, e) {
    if (e.target.value == '') e.target.value = m;
}
function bind() {
    var f = arguments.shift();
    var t = arguments.shift();
    var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return function() {
        return f.apply(t, a.concat(arguments));
    };
}
var name = document.getElementById('name');
var email = document.getElementById('email');
var message = document.getElementById('message');
[[name, 'Enter name...'],
 [email, 'Enter email...'],
 [message, 'Enter message...']].
forEach(function(field) {
    field[0].addEventListener('focus', bind(fieldFocus, null, field[1]), false);
    field[0].addEventListener('blur', bind(fieldBlur, null, field[1]), false);
});
```

Comment: yes it is very scary specially for a newbie like me :D, i would appreciate if you could explain what exactly is happening in the code.

Comment: Doesn't work. Looks like you meant `var a = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this one:**

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="Text1" name="name" class="input-text" />
<input type="text" id="Text2" name="email" class="input-text" />
<textarea name="message" id="Textarea1" class="input-textarea" ></textarea>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$("#name").focus(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Enter Name...")
        $(this).val("");
}).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "")
        $(this).val("Enter Name...");
});
$("#email").focus(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Enter Email Address...")
        $(this).val("");
}).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "")
        $(this).val("Enter Email Address...");
});
$("#message").focus(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "Enter your Message...")
        $(this).val("");
}).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val() == "")
        $(this).val("Enter your Message...");
});
```